# Android device ignores TTS settings

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a simple app that's using tts. I can't seem to change the language from english to anything else.

The following does not work

```
Locale loc = new Locale("es", "ES");
tts.setLanguage(loc);
```

or the following

```
tts.setLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);
```

or such. Does anyone know how to programmatically set the language, since the obvious is not working.

I am using an LG-P769 phone for my testing

Comment: does logcat output any warnings/errors ? Are you sure you have this language installed (data files)?

Comment: ah. The language is not available.

Comment: So... you should download the missing data and inform the user to restart the app when the download is finished. Her's a nice [tutorial] (http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-a-really-easy-tutorial-on-how-to-use-text-to-speech-tts-and-how-you-can-enter-text-and-have-it-spoken/)